# Sonoff T1 3ch connects when powered by FTDI, not when powered by mains

Tags: sonoff, tasmota

I have two Sonoff T1 3CH switches running Tasmota 12.4 which both exhibit the same problem.

1. This works. Connect the Sonoff to my laptop via FTDI. Sonoff connects to my `iot` WiFi ssid
2. This does not work. In the same physical location, connect the Sonoff to my mains supply in its wall box. Does not connect to WiFi, Blue light blinks slowly.
3. This works. With my mobile phone in the same location as my WiFi router, disable the router and open a mobile Hotspot with the same `iot` ssid.
4. I have multiple Sonoff Basics and T1 1CH and 2CH and they all work correctly.

I'm struggling for a diagnosis that fits the symptoms. The best I can come up with is that the WiFi signal is marginal on the two 3CH devices, but I'm clutching at straws. Any ideas?

Comment: what's an `iot WifI`?

Comment: @jsotola "iot" is the ssid of the WiFi network that my devices connect to